# How to print Linked List only if it contains one element in Java

Tags: java, if-statement, linked-list, iterator

I am using a Linked list/ Iterater combo to compute the Josephus problem, and need it to only print if there is only one element left in the list, but how would I use an if statement to check a condition that references to the size of the list rather than the number in the list with "ourList" being of type "LinkedList"?
Here is a piece of the code:

```
if(atEnd() == true){ 
  //System.out.println("Value removed: " + current.dData);
    previous.next = current.next;
    current = ourList.getFirst();
    //if(ourList == Only contains one element){ <--------------
    //ourList.displayList();
     // }
   }
```

for reference heres my LinkedList + Iterator:

```
class Link{

    public int dData;
    public Link next;

    public Link(int data){
        dData = data;
    }

    public void displayLink(){
        System.out.print(dData + " ");
    }

}

class LinkList{

    private Link first;

    public LinkList(){
        first = null;
    }

    public Link getFirst(){
        return first;
    }

    public void setFirst(Link f){
        first = f;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return first == null;
    }

    public ListIterator getIterator(){
        return new ListIterator(this);
    }

    public void displayList(){
        Link current = first;
        while(current != null){
            current.displayLink();
            current = current.next;
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }


}

class ListIterator{

    private Link current;
    private Link previous;
    private LinkList ourList;

    public ListIterator(LinkList list){
        ourList = list;
        reset();
    }

    public void reset(){
        current = ourList.getFirst();
        previous = null;
    }

    public boolean atEnd(){
        return(current.next == null);
    }

    public boolean atEndPrevious(){
        return(previous.next == null);
    }

    public Link getCurrent(){
        return current;
    }

    public void nextLink(){
        previous = current;
        current = current.next;
    }

    public void insert(int value){
        Link newLink = new Link(value);
        if(ourList.isEmpty() == true){
            ourList.setFirst(newLink);
            current = newLink;
        }else{
            newLink.next = current.next;
            current.next = newLink;
            nextLink();
        }
    }

    public void beginningPoint(int begin){
        if(begin == 1){
            current = ourList.getFirst();
            previous = null;
            //        System.out.println("Current Location: " + current.dData);
        }else if(begin != 1){
            current = ourList.getFirst();
            previous = null;
            for(int i = 1; i < begin; i++){
                nextLink();
                //          System.out.println("Current Location: " + current.dData);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: ideally for a linked list with only one element i.e. head, head->next should be null. Use that to your advantage if you are not using a standard LinkedList library. If you are, linkedList.size()==1 should work

Comment: I would thumbs up your comment if I could, did if(current.next == null) {...} , thank you

Comment: No worries. Glad i could help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding pseudocode, since it will help you understand the process, but learn by programming it yourself. Also note you could remove some `else`'s through the behavior of exiting.

All of this functions through the iterator.

```
if at end
  dont print and exit (0 elements)
else
  get and save next element to variable
  if at end
    print the variable you saved (only 1 element)
  else
    dont print and exit (more than 1 element)
```